# Add-Migration showing previous changes

Tags: entity-framework

I'm working on Entity Framework migrations.

when i change the model and use add-migration its working good but when i change my model for the second time and run the add-migration command the generated file is containing the sql changes which i made first and second.

Can any one please tell me why i'm having this behavior.

here is the model

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Property(p => p.NewCol2).HasColumnName("ColChanged");
    }

public class Department
{
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public int DivNo { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
public string NewCol2 { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{

    public int EmpNo { get; set; }
    public int DivisionNo { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
 }
```

I wanted to change the NewCol2 name to ColChange and i wrote the property in ModelBuilder and i got the generated file as shown below.

First cs file

Only the Up()

```
 AddColumn("dbo.Departments", "ColChanged", c => c.String());
```

When i tried to change the EMPName to required by adding [Required] annotation i got the generated file as below

Second cs file

```
     AddColumn("dbo.Departments", "ColChanged", c => c.String());
    AlterColumn("dbo.Employees", "EmpName", c => c.String(nullable: false));
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you doing an `update-database` after `add-migration`?

Comment: yes..I'm doing update-database

Comment: post your model and migration .cs-s generated - or any SQL when update - like a small step-by-step - so we could see what's going on, hard to say on one sentence. Also check your connection (though I doubt it)

Comment: Delete old `Migrations` and it will solve your problems. Its precisely this reason i don't run `add-migrations`, especially if i am following `ef code-first`.

Answer (score 3):

One place I've seen this happen is where you're working in a collaborative environment and two people add-migration on independent branches. Both these migrations serialize the state of the model into their __MigrationHistory table entry (which is what is stored in the migration's resx file).

Then when the changes are merged together onto a single branch, the migrations look fine from the outside - one of them comes after the other in the project - but the latest migration (let's call it 'B') doesn't contain the changes to the model that the preceding migration ('A') contains.

Calling update-database runs through all the migrations and brings the database up to date as expected. However, the problem comes when a third migration, 'C', is added. This migration uses the serialized model state from 'B' to understand the delta to the model. However, as the  serialized model from 'B' doesn't contain the changes that 'A' represents, migration 'C' then attempts to generate SQL statements to cover the changes in both 'A' and 'C'.

The solution to this is to go back to migration 'A', removing 'B' and 'C' and ensuring the database is in a state where only 'A' is applied. Then add-migration to create one covering 'B' and 'C'.

To prevent this in future it should be the responsibility of the person integrating code into their branch to delete and recreate their migration if they discover that they have just merged in someone else's migration.